# problame to auth login in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

here its my code for the the login action in my users controller

```
public function login() {
    if($this->Session->check('Auth.User')) {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome, '. $this->Auth->User('username')));
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password'));
        }
    }
}
```

i have the problame with the login using the auth.

Can anyone suggest to me how to solve this problame is cakephp version 2.6.4

Comment: actually when i am printing the auth->login() it gives the result like this Array() even the record is exists in the database. even i also puth the auth component inside the app controller still not working is there any reason behind it ?

Comment: i m trying to do a login module using cakephp.i know it's give a bolean value but still its not give a 0 else 1 not any value its given and in my database the password is store with the help of Md5PasswordHasher at time of registration process i m store password in database using that.and when i m try to login using that password it's not give a return value from the auth->login.

Comment: So your question/problem is that you can't login - not that there's an error. You should check your sql log, and the submitted and stored password hash. Please **edit the question** with new information, don't write comments. Also if you're just starting out - note that 2.x is not the current version of CakePHP, would be better to start with 3.x.

Comment: Thanks but from where i have to check my sql log?i can not use the 3.x version we have to work on the 2.x version only.and i am register as a password admin and in login i also type the admin still it can not given any output from the Auth->login

Comment: [Use debug kit](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html#debug-kit). At this point your problem is not that auth doesn't work, it's that you need  to do basic debugging.

Comment: with the help of the debug kit it shows the query without the where condition of the password its showing only username in the where condition and the auth->login is not give any response or any error message nothing came from that function if you have any idea then please let me know how can i solve this problame?

Comment: You are not reading/actioning my comments - I can't help you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and i already reading your comment and do like that.but still i dont know how to solve that problame with the auth login if you have any solution then will you please give to me.